# How to set a Date in apex test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, date, datetime

I have written a test class in which I just want to set one date field. How can I achieve this? I am not able to set the value using the following code:

```
Account acc=new Account();
acc.effectiveDate__c= '09.12.2016';
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do this using Apex' Date class:

```
acc.effectiveDate__c = Date.newInstance(2016, 12, 9);
```

For more information check out the documentation: [Apex Developer Guide - Date Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

Comment: Gosh I wish you could use date literals like in SOQL for setting fields in Apex  Couldn't find an Idea in the IdeaExchange yet.
acc.EffectiveDate__c = 2016-09-12;

Answer (score 7):

Another option is using `system.today()` (or `system.now()` if it's `datetime` field):

```
acc.effectiveDate__c = System.today() + 5;
```

Comment: This is what I personally try to use in my own unit tests. I find that not hard-coding a specific date helps in writing better date-centric logic.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using system.today().addDays(10)

`acc.effectiveDate__c = System.today().addDays(10);`

Answer (score -2):

a.SLAExpirationDate__c = date.parse('4/17/2020');

You need to use date.parse to execute the code

Comment: It's not necessary to instantiate dates in this specific manner.

Comment: Not only is it unnecessary, it is a very poor idea, because Date parsing depends on the running user's locale.